# Why tracking pixels opposed to JavaScript calls? Aren't there caching issues?

Tags: php, tracking, visitors, automation, tracking-pixel

As I understand it, a "**tracking pixel**" is a script that contains code that includes a header that make the response appear to be an image, which is then called using an image tag, like:

```
<img src="mytrackingpixel.php">
```

...so that the code runs automatically/silently, when the page loads the images, for tracking or other purposes.

---

If I'm correct *so far*, then my questions are:

1. **What's the advantage?** How is this any different from just `include`ing another `.js` file, with the same code?
2. **Images are often cached** (but also refreshed sometimes) - so won't the code run at somewhat unpredictably/irregularly?

Comment: oh and # - do they sometimes have actual images attached?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few reasons one might choose tracking pixels over a script:

- Images are less likely to be blocked on the client-side than scripts.
- You can easily prevent the pixel from being cached (and therefore prevent any cache jank) by using a `Cache-Control` HTTP header that tells the browser to never cache the pixel.
- For basic server-side tracking, JavaScript is not needed anyways, as the server can get all the info it wants from the HTTP headers.
- If you are doing server-side tracking, a tracking pixel is simpler to implement than JavaScript code.

Tracking pixels and tracking JavaScript both have their pros and cons. The tracking pixel is a simple, basic server-side approach that is often enough if the webmaster's needs are not too advanced.